# Export Postgres sequences only

Tags: postgresql, export, sequence

Is there a way using `PG_DUMP` or any other commands to export only sequences from an existing database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "export sequences".

I suppose that you mean to extract all statements as:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE [sequence name] ....;

ALTER SEQENCE [sequence name] OWNED BY [table name]
```

If that's so than I would do `pg_dump` of db and then parse extract all sequence related DDL-statements.

E.g.

```bash
# CREATE SEQUENCE
$  pg_restore db.dump --section=pre-data  -f - | awk  '/CREATE SEQUENCE/ {print}' FS="\n" RS=""
CREATE SEQUENCE public.address_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
...

# ALTER SEQUENCE
$ pg_restore db.dump --section=pre-data  -f - | awk  '/ALTER SEQUENCE/ {print}' FS="\n"       
ALTER SEQUENCE public.address_id_seq OWNED BY public.address.id;
....
```

Note: `gawk 5.1.0` was used.

Possible alterations:

- db dump file is not required - redirect output of pg_dump directly to `awk`
- no need to dump data. `pg_dump --schema-only` will be enough

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -d namedb -U postgres -t '*_id_seq' > dump-seq.sql
```

Comment: You may want to add short description of what this command does and why it answers the question.

Comment: The `-t` parameter in pg_dump is normally used for tables. Will this really work for sequences?

Comment: Dump only tables with names matching table. For this purpose, "table" includes views, materialized views, sequences, and foreign tables.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html